# Fresh Gentoo Installation - Kernel Panic

Tags: kernel, boot, uefi, gentoo, kernel-panic

I recently installed Gentoo on my Toshiba Tecra A50-A-151. Unfortunately, I am getting a kernel panic when it boots. I followed the Gentoo wiki handbook (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation) using U.E.F.I. and the *efibootmgr* (not GRUB). I am also using *OpenRC* as opposed to *systemd*.

I believe the kernel is compiled with the correct options, including all of the E.F.I. support added:

- `CONFIG_EFI`
- `CONFIG_EFI_STUB`
- `CONFIG_EFI_MIXED`
- `CONFIG_EFI_VARS`
- `CONFIG_EFI_ESRT`
- `CONFIG_EFI_RUNTIME_MAP`
- `CONFIG_EFI_RUNTIME_WRAPPERS`
- `CONFIG_EFIVAR_FS`

`CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL` is also enabled while `CONFIG_CMDLINE` is set to `/dev/sda2`: the FAT32-formatted partition.

Following are images of the bootup process (in order).

[image: Stage 1]
[image: Stage 2]
[image: Stage 3]

I cannot see anything of immediate interest (aside from the final image with the panic) from these logs. The only thing I suspected was the inability to open *regulatory.db* with error code -2 (I assume that is the standard `errno` set by `fopen`). This led me to [this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/kernel-platform-regulatory-0-direct-firmware-load-for-regulatory-db-failed-with-error-2-a-4175622954/), however both `/lib/firmware/regulatory.db` and `/lib/firmware/regulatory.db.p7s` do exist on my system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does any precompiled EFI-capable distribution boot there, e.g. GRML or ALT Rescue?

Comment: Can you try booting with the "noapic" parameter set?